# Source not found

Tags: solidity, react

I'm following a tutorial on freeCodeCamp and on my contract:
I'm getting an error on `import "hardhat/console.sol";`

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter {
    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        console.log("Deploying a Greeter with greeting:", _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        console.log("Changing greeting from '%s' to '%s'", greeting, _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

Error:
Source "hardhat/console.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

When change the path to:

```
import "../node_modules/hardhat/console.sol";
```

It works but then I'm unable to compile

However if I go to the file directly like this:

```
import "C:/Users/limco/Desktop/Dev- Fullstack/react-dapp/node_modules/hardhat/console.sol";
```

It works and compiles, I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

If your project file structure is something like:

- Project

  - client
  - smart_contracts

    - contracts
      *contract_A.sol

you'll experience this error especially assuming you're in VSCode cd'ed into the sub directory. You need to open the 'smart_contracts' directory as the root when you execute commands such as `npx hardhat test` etc. When 'smart_contracts' is the root it will work - though, you might get an error:

> opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],

which you can fix by running

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Good luck!